# c# regex and [] expression , why does [+*/-] fail to parse?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i tried to use Regex in c# , but the following code throws an exception:

```
string pattern = "(\d+)([+*/-])(\d+)";

Regex reg = new Regex  (pattern);
```

After a little dig , i found that in c# if you try to match '-' with [] expression , it must be put as the first character in that bracket , which confused me.

Could someone jump out and explain that to me ?

Appreciate any of your responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-` character takes on a special meaning within a character class `[...]` to denote a range, so that shorthand expressions like the following work:

```
"[a-z]" // matches all lowercase alphabetic characters without having to specify them all.
```

The `-` is only interpreted literally if it is the first character simply because it can't denote a range because no other value precedes it.

Honestly, it should make no difference whether it is the first or the last character.

Comment: quick joe smith is too quick.

Comment: Joe - While I consider it best practice to escape the hyphen anyway, it isn't needed in this case. `[abc-]` is valid in the majority of regex flavors. See also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: What @Kobi said. I don't recall .NET ever having problems with `-` being the last character of a CC.

Comment: Here's the pattern on .Net, using [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cd%2b)(%5b%2b*%2f-%5d)(%5cd%2b)&i=2*4+5-7+23%2f6), seems to be working as expected `:)`

Answer (score 5):

That code doesn't throw a runtime exception - that code **doesn't compile**, with the error "Unrecognized escape sequence" - you didn't escape the backslashes properly. `\d` isn't a valid escape character.

This should work:

```
string pattern = "(\\d+)([+*/-])(\\d+)";
```

Or this, using [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#8276d6fc-ed51-4e74-b698-a04a125ccdbb):

```
string pattern = @"(\d+)([+*/-])(\d+)";
```

Comment: Sorry , that's a mistake made my me , i forgot to append the "@" symbol in my question , but thanks for spotting that !